# How do I use YAML in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of accounts I want to save as a YAML file and load it into ruby.  Something like this:

> ```
> Account1
>   John Smith
>   jsmith
>   jsmith@gmail.com
> Account2
>   John Doe
>   jdoe
>   jdoe@hotmail.com
> ```

Then I want to get the email address of the person with the name of "John Doe" (for example).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here, you save your yaml objects as Person objects and then when you load them back, they will load into Person objects, making them a lot easier to handle.

First change tweak your yaml file to something like this:

```
--- 
- !ruby/object:Person 
  name: John Doe
  sname: jdoe
  email: jdoe@gmail.com
- !ruby/object:Person 
  name: Jane Doe
  sname: jdoe
  email: jane@hotmail.com
```

Now you can load your yaml file into an array of Person objects and then manipulate the array:

```
FILENAME = 'data.yaml'

class Person 
 attr_accessor :name, :sname, :email
end

require "yaml"
# Will return an array of Person objects.
data = YAML::load(File.open(FILENAME))

# Will print out the first object in the array's name. #=> John Doe
puts data.first.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You just say `require yaml` at the top of your file.

Objects get a `to_yaml` method when you do this. Loading of yaml files is easy to.. Refer to the docs here. 
http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/