# YAML in, YAML out -- general questions / guidance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a survey application that I build surveys in by hand, and I want to add an option to build surveys by file, yaml seems fit the needs of this application. I'd like to upload a yaml file, and then outputting a yaml file from previously built surveys would be nice.

Looking around, I haven't found the tutorial I need for learning how to parse a yaml file into a several db objects (answers, answer areas, answer types, various other things about the survey, etc).

I'm wondering if anyone has any tips, guides, or some wonder tool/plugin that I haven't seen yet, etc.

Just a thought any input appreciated.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002092/how-do-i-use-yaml-in-ruby-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your YAML file will turn into a nested data structure. Each level will be either an `Array` or a `Hash.` It's probably easiest to just `#pp()` it and take a look to get started.

```
require 'pp'
require 'yaml'

pp YAML.load_file('f.yaml')
```