# Ruby on Rails YAML configuration design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, configuration, model, yaml

I have a lot of static preferences for one entity. Do I need to store them in database table? Or I could use YAML configuration file, with approximate structure:

```
name: "Lights"
descriptions: ""
items: 
  title: "Fog lighs"
  description: "Should be used in foggy environment only!"

  title: "Xenon"
  description: "6500K"

name "Safety"
description: "Safety systems"
items:
  title: "Airbag"
  description: ""

  title: "ABS"
  description: "bla bla bla"
```

with [ruby/object model markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002092/how-do-i-use-yaml-in-ruby-rails). Can this be done with a nesting structure like in my example above?

Can somebody tell, if it is a good practice to do so? I don't want to use database, because these settings would be pretty much static, with low probability of need to change anything.

If it is possible, I would also like to know how to implement translation (i18n) for the elements of the structure (names and titles). I don't know where to put it in this particular situation.

Or I should use an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course use YAML in your rails app the same way you would from any ruby app:

```
require 'yaml'
things = YAML::load(open("my_things.yml"))
```

For translation just use the existing Rails I18n framework.

For example, given the classes:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :title, :description
end

class Lights < Thing
end

class Safety < Thing
end
```

And the following YAML data file:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Lights
  title: "Fog lights"
  description: "Should be used in foggy environments only!"
- !ruby/object:Lights
  title: "Xenon"
  description: "6500K"
- !ruby/object:Safety
  title: "Airbag"
- !ruby/object:Safety
  title: "ABS"
  description: "bla bla bla"
```

You can add the translation in config/locale/things.nb.yml:

```
nb:
  lights:
    fog_lights:
      title: "Tåkelys"
      description: "Kun til bruk i tåke!"
    xenon:
      title: "Xenon"
      description: "6500K"
  safety:
    airbag:
      title: "Kollisjonspute"
    abs:
      title: "ABS"
      description: "bla bla bla"
```

Similar for other languages, of course. Now let's implement a method to describe a thing:

```
class Thing
  def describe
    key = title.parameterize
    thing = self.class.to_s.downcase
    translated_title = I18n::t("#{thing}.#{key}.title")
    if description
      translated_description = I18n::t("#{thing}.#{key}.description")
    else
      translated_description = ""
    end
    "#{translated_title}: #{translated_description}"
  end
end
```

Assuming the current language is Norwegian, you can now do:

```
things.each do |thing|
  puts thing.describe
end
```

and get:

```
Tåkelys: Kun til bruk i tåke!
Xenon: 6500K
Kollisjonspute: 
ABS: bla bla bla
```

Notice you may either drop the description tags from the original YAML file, or have them as default fallbacks if there is no translation available.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh. By the way. Can i somehow load all of the items from this YAML file into array or object collection or something ?

Comment: YAML::load(open(filename)) gives you a Hash with the entire YML-tree.

Comment: OK. But is there a way to keep them as objects like here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002092/how-do-i-use-yaml-in-ruby-rails

Comment: Yes, the same method should work. But mixing this into the I18n-system may not be a good idea. You should then separate the objects and the translation.

Comment: The idea with separation sound fine to me, but how to do it ? How to translate then ?

Comment: You should be able to use the keys from the original YML file to lookup the localized text for that entry. Or if you make objects, have the class do it.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much for your support. I would be very grateful to you if you could provide some super-simple code example. Just to be sure that I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

you should have:

```
en:
  thing1:
    name: "Lights"
    descriptions: ""
   items:
      item1: 
        title: "Fog lighs"
        description: "Should be used in foggy environment only!"
      item2:
        title: "Xenon"
        description: "6500K"
es:
  thing1:
    name "translation"
    description: "translation"
    items:
      item1:
        title: "translation"
        description: "translation"
      item2:
        title: "translation"
        description: "translation"
```

Comment: OK! Got it. But how do you think, is it a good practice ? 
How about translations ?

Comment: Ah. OK! Thank you so much for your fast and accurate response!